# How to stop the default browser of ColdFusion Builder?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

Each time I starts Coldfusion builder, the default browser of Coldfusion builder starts, Which makes the whole startup more slower.
Its too annoying . Is there any way to stop that browser from being start at the beginning?

I have search for many settings but I did not find anything.

Comment: Are you talking about the Welcome Screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the Welcome Screen. It is a bit small, but in the lower left (maybe right) is a checkbox that says, "Don't Show This Again."

Just check it. :)